# How can I add an FK constraint to my entity model without adding it to the DB?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework model with table Employees.  Each employee has a SupervisorId, which points to another record in the same Employees table.  The entity model VS inferred from my DB design looked fine, but I could not update or insert records for the table with the self-reference.  I have taken to using a view of the Employees table for the Supervisors table, but I cannot add an FK constraint to a view in the database.  How can I do this, or achieve the same effect, in the EF designer?

At worst I can skip the FK constrain, but would like to know how to use and populated a standard or custom combobox so the Employee form still offers a choice of Supervisors when editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a "foreign key" to the Entity Model without adding it to the database - the FK is a database design construct to link to tables, and as such would have to be added to the storage model (the physical database model) in EF - but that has to be 1:1 what exists in the acutal database.

But what you could do is to add an Association to your conceptual model; this is the side of things that is *not* tied 1:1 to the database, but represents your domain model. You can add this by means of right-clicking on an entity in your EDMX designer and choosing "Add association" from the context menu.

[image]

This will popup a "Add Association" dialog in which you can pick what two entities to link, and how:

[image]

With this, you should be able to add Associations and thus relationships between entities on the conceptual side of the EF model, without touching the underlying database schema.

Marc

Comment: Thanks @Marc, but how do I relate the association's navigation properties with actual objects, e.g. in your example, how do I popall the Entries for a Contract?

Comment: Yeah, sorry - that doesn't seem to work - it still insists on being mapped to a FK-relationship in the database :-( I was hoping it would be able to resolve that association in the conceptual model alone - no luck :-(

Comment: +1 For trying, but my problem isn't solved, so sorry, close but no Accept, hehe.